# How do I subclass RequestHandler to automatically validate arguments?

Tags: tornado, python-3.2

I have the following code:

```
class CounterIDHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, counter_id):
        try:
            object_id = bson.objectid.ObjectId(counter_id)
        except bson.errors.InvalidId as e:
            self.finish(json_encode({'e': str(e)}))
            return
            # I want to finish execution here

class CounterHandler(CounterIDHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, counter_id):
        super().get(counter_id)
        print("this should not print if we get exception in super().get")
        try:
            # I want to use object_id here
        except Exception as e:
            self.finish(json_encode({'e': str(e)}))
```

This obviously doesn't work but it shows what I am trying to do.
`self.finish()` terminates connection with the client but it does not terminate execution.

I want to validate that counter_id is a valid object_id without copy pasting code in all Handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting this in `get()` in the base class?  It looks to me like this should go in a separate `get_object_id` method.  In any case, there are two ways for the shared method to affect the caller: exceptions and the return value.

Using a return value of None to signal that the caller should stop:

```
class CounterIDHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get_object_id(self, counter_id):
        try:
            return bson.objectid.ObjectId(counter_id)
        except bson.errors.InvalidId as e:
            self.finish(json_encode({'e': str(e)}))
            return None

class CounterHandler(CounterIDHandler):
    def get(self, counter_id):
        object_id = self.get_object_id(counter_id)
        if object_id is None:
            return
```

Or with exceptions and a `write_error` handler:

```
class CounterIDHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get_object_id(self, counter_id):
        return bson.objectid.ObjectId(counter_id)

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        if 'exc_info' in kwargs:
            typ, exc, tb = kwargs['exc_info']
            if isinstance(exc, bson.errors.InvalidId):
                self.finish(json_encode({'e': str(e)}))
                return
        super(CounterIDHandler, self).write_error(status_code, **kwargs)

class CounterHandler(CounterIDHandler):
    def get(self, counter_id):
        object_id = self.get_object_id()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a decorator, something like this (untested):

```
def oid_validator(f):
    @web.asynchronous
    def wrapped(self, oid_str):
        try:
            oid = bson.objectid.ObjectId(oid_str)
        except bson.errors.InvalidId as e:
            self.finish(json_encode({'e': str(e)}))
        else:
            coro = gen.coroutine(f)
            coro(self, oid)
```

Then instead of decorating your `get()` methods with `@gen.coroutine`, you can decorate them with `@oid_validator`:

```
class CounterIDHandler(RequestHandler):
    @oid_validator
    def get(self, counter_id):
        # counter_id is now an ObjectId instance
```

Comment: Really cool solution, I think it is very general and you can use it everytime you need a validator, but in this case I like Ben's solution better.